# error in modulus method in ruby

Tags: ruby, modulus

I am trying to write a method that takes in an array as an argument and returns an array of the numbers in the argument that are have both an even index number and an even value. I am not sure why, but it is giving me the error  "undefined method %" in line 5. Can someone explain how I can fix this?

```
def odd_value_and_position(array)
    newArray=[] #create new array
    i=0 #i=0
    while i <= array.length #loop while
        newArray.push(array[i]) if array[i] % 2 != 0
        i = i + 2
    end

    return newArray
end

puts odd_value_and_position([0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: This is because when i = 6 the loop runs and `array[6]` is `nil` use `i < array.length`

Comment: common off by one error, always have to be careful of those!

Comment: you should use the .even? method instead of using a modulo

Comment: Do you want even or odd? Inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this:

```
def evens arr
  arr.select.with_index { |e,i| e.even? && i.even? }
end

evens [0,1,2,3,4,5] #=> [0,2,4]
```

Comment: Nice. No, let's see what the OP really wanted. Is the first index odd or even? :)

Answer (score 1):

When `i` is equal to `array.length`, `array[i]` is nil.

What is `nil % 2`? It is undefined.

```
def odd_value_and_position(array)
    newArray=[] #create new array
    i=0 #i=0
    while i < array.length #loop while
        newArray.push(array[i]) if array[i] % 2 != 0
        i = i + 2
    end

    return newArray
end

puts odd_value_and_position([0,1,2,3,4,5]) #=> []
puts odd_value_and_position([1,2,3,4,5])   #=> [1,3,5]
```

Due to the fact that the first element in a Ruby Array has 0 as index, I'm not sure you get the result you expected. See examples in code.

A more Rubyish example would be :

```
def odd_value_and_position(array)
  array.select.with_index(1){|x,i| x.odd? && i.odd?}
end

puts odd_value_and_position([1,2,3,4,5]) #=> [1,3,5]
```

Comment: The question and the method are misleading since the question states *"an even index number and an even value"* but the method name suggests the opposite (which you have posted) but then the method body is searching even indexes for odd numbers. I have no idea what is going on now but +1 for a reasonable explanation.

Comment: The method should be called `even_or_odd_or_something`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right, I'd go with something like:

```
def some_method_name(array)
  array.select.with_index { |*ij| 
    ij.all?(&:even?)
  }
end

puts some_method_name([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 13, 21, 22, 30])

# >> 0
# >> 2
# >> 4
# >> 10
# >> 30
```

Here's what it's doing:

```
def some_method_name(array)
  array.select.with_index { |*ij| 
    ij               # => [0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [10, 6], [13, 7], [21, 8], [22, 9], [30, 10]
    ij.all?(&:even?) # => true,   false,  true,   false,  true,   false,  true,    false,   false,   false,   true
  }
end

puts some_method_name([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 13, 21, 22, 30])

# >> 0
# >> 2
# >> 4
# >> 10
# >> 30
```

There are a couple problems with the original code.

Using `while` loops easily leads to problems with off-by-one errors, or loops that never trigger, or loops that never end.

To combat that in Ruby, we use `each` and `map`, `select`, `reject` or similar iterators to loop over the array, and process each element in turn, then base the logic on that.

`array.select` is looking at each element and applying the logic in the block, looking for "truthy" results. `with_index` adds the index of the iteration as a second value passed into the block. `*id` turns the two values being passed in into an array, making it easy to apply `all?` and its `even?` test. If `even?` returns `true` to both then `all?` triggers and returns `true` again which signals to `select` to return that element of the array.

Comment: 3 equivalent answers for this question. But what is the question exactly? That's the question :D

Comment: A little picky are we?

Comment: Let's say it's just a higher standard than for everybody else, due to your reputation and the quality of your answers on other questions. Since Ruby is dynamic, method names are extremely important. Your edit is perfectly fine, now.